# What should be the correct way to access the function I am calling?

Tags: solidity, contract-invocation

I want to create an auction for every item. So I am using this setup

```
function createAuction()  public {
    

    Auction newAuction = new Auction("arguments here");

    auctions.push(address(newAuction)); 
}

function getHighestBidder(uint index) public view returns(address){
    address buyer = auctions(index).getHighestBidder();

}
```

But solidity gives me an error saying

> from solidity: TypeError: Type is not callable   -->
> contracts/auctionFactory.sol:30:25:    | 30 |         address buyer =
> auctions(index).getHighestBidder();    |
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

How do I access the said function?

Comment: Can you share all your smart contract code?

Comment: Contract I am creating:

Comment: Hi @VarunKumar! Welcome to Ethereum Stackexchange! What type is `auctions`? Is it a mapping? an array? a function? a contract?

Comment: an  address array

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.